# extra dictionary key added in for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I'm try to write a python function that takes a dict with movie titles as keys and a list of performers in that movie as values, and returns a new dict with performers as keys and the movies they appear in as values. This code comes close, but returns something different for each run.

Here is the original function call:

```
    movies = {"How to Be Single": ["Alison Brie", "Dakota Johnson",
                               "Rebel Wilson"],
              "The Lego Movie": ["Will Arnett", "Elizabeth Banks",
                             "Alison Brie", "Will Ferrell"]}
    print(stars,movies)
```

Here is the code:

```
def stars(movies):
# create a new dictionary
films_dict= {}
performances_films = []

# for each movie actor, add as key to new_dict
for movie, actors in movies.items():
    for actor in actors:
        if not actor in films_dict.keys():
            #print(actor)
            performances_films = []
            performances_films.append(movie)
            films_dict[actor] = performances_films
        else:
            performances_films.append(movie)
            films_dict[actor] = performances_films

return(films_dict)
```

Here is the output:

```
RUN 1
    {'Rebel Wilson': ['How to Be Single'], 'Will Ferrell': ['The Lego 
    Movie'], 
    'Will Arnett': ['The Lego Movie'], 'Elizabeth Banks': ['The Lego Movie', 
    'The Lego Movie'], 'Alison Brie': ['The Lego Movie', 'The Lego Movie'], 
    'Dakota Johnson': ['How to Be Single']}

RUN 2
{'Will Arnett': ['The Lego Movie'], 'Dakota Johnson': ['How to Be Single'], 'Elizabeth Banks': ['The Lego Movie', 'The Lego Movie'], 'Rebel Wilson': ['How to Be Single'], 'Will Ferrell': ['The Lego Movie'], 'Alison Brie': ['The Lego Movie', 'The Lego Movie']}
```

I think its either iterating through the dict items in a different order each run, or saving data from one run to the next. Either way I can't seem to resolve it.

Comment: Python dictionaries are unordered, which is why the output changes for each run. If you want to keep consistent order of items in the dictionary you may want to use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get why you're keeping a `performances_films` list around. You can just use the ones you created previously in the `dict` itself.

Here's something I think will work:

```
def stars(movies):
    # create a new dictionary
    films_dict= {}

    # for each movie actor, add as key to new_dict
    for movie, actors in movies.items():
        for actor in actors:
            if not actor in films_dict.keys():
                performances_films = []
                performances_films.append(movie)
                films_dict[actor] = performances_films
            else:
                films_dict[actor].append(movie)

    return(films_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
movies = {"How to Be Single": ["Alison Brie", "Dakota Johnson",
                               "Rebel Wilson"],
              "The Lego Movie": ["Will Arnett", "Elizabeth Banks",
                             "Alison Brie", "Will Ferrell"]}
stars = {}
for movie, v in movies.items():
    for star in v:
        if star in stars:
            stars[star].append(movie)
        else:
            stars[star] = [movie]

print(stars)
```

prints:

```
{'Alison Brie': ['How to Be Single', 'The Lego Movie'], 'Dakota Johnson': ['How to Be Single'], 'Rebel Wilson': ['How to Be Single'], 'Will Arnett': ['The Lego Movie'], 'Elizabeth Banks': ['The Lego Movie'], 'Will Ferrell': ['The Lego Movie']}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake in your code is that the `list` instance `performances_films` is persisting from one loop iteration to the next. That's why (say) Alison Brie has The Lego Movie listed twice—it was really supposed to be added for *another* actor, but the `list` instance previously created for Alison Brie was still occupying the name slot `performances_films`.  In fact it looks like multiple actors might be sharing that same `list` instance.

You can simplify the code a lot if you use the "default value" concept when accessing your dictionary.  This is either done by using the [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) class:

```
import collections
filmography = collections.defaultdict(list)
for movie, actors in movies.items():
    for actor in actors:
        filmography[actor].append(movie)
```

or my preferred way would be with a vanilla `dict` and its [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method:

```
filmography = {}                     
for movie, actors in movies.items():
    for actor in actors:
        filmography.setdefault(actor, []).append(movie)
```

Either way, you can treat each new movie uniformly without having to test explicitly for the actor's prior membership of `filmography`.